# What is the best way to convert a Buffer to a custom base?

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, radix

How to output a string representation of a Buffer in a custom base? (ie. octal, base26, base58, base64, ...)

I surprised myself to find it particularly challenging to recode this without external libraries like BN (using only NodeJS native ones at most)

```
const buff = Buffer.from('a4fe800c32', 'hex');

// OK
console.log(buff.toString('base64'));

// Would like
console.log(buff.toString('base58'));

// Or
const customBase = ['0', '1', '2', 'a', '§', 'K'];
console.log(buff.toString(customBase));
```

Comment: There is a limited number of encodings available natively in node: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/buffer.js#L597

Comment: Absolutely, but still very limited

Answer (score -1):

You could try using [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite).

In the [wiki](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/wiki/Modifying-encoding-tables) it's explained how to create a new custom encoding.

Comment: My question is not about encoding, but numeric bases